# Probability minimum value question

Tags: probability

A bag contains some coloured counters, some of these counters are black. You remove two counters from the bag and they are both black.  The probability of you doing this was 132/380.  What is the minimum number of counters in the bag and how many of these are black?

Comment: What work have you done so far? Do you have any thoughts about how to do the problem?

Comment: Thankyou for your replyI have been asked to proofread a maths resource and have found that this level of probability question is out of my reach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume there are $n$ counters, $k$ of which are black. The probability of removing a black counter on the first turn equals $\frac{k}{n}$, and the probability of removing a black counter on the second turn (given a successful first turn) equals $\frac{k-1}{n-1}$. In order for $k (k-1)$ to equal 132 and $n (n-1)$ to equal 380, $k$ must be 12 and $n$ must be 20. Indeed:

$$\frac{12}{20} \cdot \frac{11}{19} = \frac{132}{380}$$

Comment: Many thanks, that's perfectly clear now